# Converting normally distributed numbers to uniform distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I have a Perlin noise algorithm I've written my self. It seems to produce gausian numbers at the range of -1.5 and 1.5 but I'll convert them to the range of -1 and 1. I' currently working on a project that requires numbers of a uniform distribution. So how do I convert normally distributed numbers to a uniform distribution?

Comment: Can't you get random numbers directly, instead of converting Gaussian numbers to random numbers, if you are using some kind of programming language ?

Comment: Mostly people do this the other way around. i.e. convert uniform random variables, which are abundant, to other random variables.

Comment: With the current tools(?) I have I can't. The code I use only produces gausian numbers. Since it is possible to convert uniform numbers to normally distributed ones I thought it would be possible the other way round.

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous rv and $F$ its cdf, then $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed. However, like the other said, it is more expansive generated gaussian random numbers then uniform random numbers.